# Dynamic initialization using loops in ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-1.9.3

Simple problem in looping and dynamic assignment, need suggestion.

Problem:

```
@var = 1

def meth
 @values = (#here a query uses @var value to calculate and returns some values)
end

meth #calling meth function

# value of @value increaser when i increase @var
# i need to increment @var by 10 each time and have to call meth for @values=10

if @values.lenght < 10
 # Here how can i iterate 
  10.times do |x|
  @var += 10
  meth 
 end
 # calling meth with incremented value @var
end
```

I am not getting how to iterate the the method.

Comment: what is your expected output? and what do you get instead?

Comment: i supposed to get 10 '@values'.

Mean for '@var = 1' ,i run 'meth' function ,if i dint get 10 '@values' i need to increment '@var' value and again run the 'meth' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize `@values` before using it, otherwise it seems to work:

```
@var = 1
@values = []

def meth
  @values << @var
end

meth

10.times do
  @var += 10
  meth
end

p @values #=> [1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101, 101]
```

Comment: yeah i declared that array . BUt missed iterating in loop

Comment: and you have to use `@values <<` instead of `@values =` in order to *add* objects to the array (`=` would replace the entire array, which is certainly not what you want)